# python-Django Не обрабатывается форма добавления записей в модель

Tags: python, django

Наткнулся на такую проблему, что, отправляя типичнейшую форму с шаблона, она обрабатывается, но не сохраняет данные, в смысле в модели этой записи просто нет. Даже пришлось по туториалу Djangogirls делать -_-" а толку всё равно 0. Просто уже не понимаю, что тут не так!

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('caption', 'text')
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import PostForm

def blog(request): #Вьюха ПРОСТО для вывода постов на основную страницу
    post = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog.html', locals())

def addPost(request): #Вьюха для добавления поста
    form = PostForm() #Объявление формы forms.py
    if request.method == "POST": #Если метод отправки формы из шаблона = POST
        form = PostForm(request.POST) #Принять данные из формы шаблона к форме forms.py
        if form.is_valid(): #Доп. проверка на валидность формы
            post = form.save() #Объявление переменной на сохранение формы
            post.save() #Сохранение формы
            return redirect('accept') #переход на вьюху 'accept' где просто респонс "Удачное добавление"
    else:
        form = PostForm() #Если метод отправки не POST, то форма forms.py так и остается пустой
    return render(request, 'addpost.html', {'form': form})

def accept(request):

    return HttpResponse('Successfully adding')
```

Форма в шаблоне:

```
<form method="POST" action="/accept">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: А отладчиком пользуетесь? Какая среда разработки?

Comment: Sublime'ом пользуюсь

Comment: В саблайме нет отладчика. Воспользуйтесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/348376/ утилиткой или скачайте pycharm, чтобы продебажить код

Answer (score 0):

Убрать (в Views.py 9 строка) - просто не нужно:

```
form = PostForm()
```

Вместо (в Views.py):

```
post = form.save()
post.save()
```

написать:

```
form.save()
```